# java to vb.net - linkedlist to arraylist

Tags: java, vb.net

I am converting java code to vb.net and this line of code gives me different output in eclipse than the one in VS.

```
req1.set(req3, Integer.valueOf(((Integer)req1.get(req3)).intValue() ^ ((Integer)req6.get(req3 + 256)).intValue() & 0x1));
System.out.println(req1.get(req3));
```

where `req1` is linkedlist,
`req3` is int, and
`req6` is linkedlist

and here is my vb.net snippet

```
req1(req3) = (req1(req3) Xor req6(req3 + 256) & &H1)
ListBox1.Items.Add(req1(req3))
```

where `req1` is arraylist
`req3` is integer
`req6` is arraylist

output in eclipse (Correct One)

1

0

0

1

output in VS (Incorrect One)

60

661

970

411

All the code before this works perfectly in both IDEs.

Comment: Break up the code (especially thee Java) and check the temporary values

Comment: if I print values just before setting value at some index, both give me same output as: 1 0 1 0

Comment: What are the values in the lists to start with?

Comment: 1 0 1 0 are the first 4 values in both lists

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but what is at req6(req3 + 256)? If req3 is 0, req6 must be a very long list.

Comment: I fixed it finally thanks everyone. I had to use "And" keyword inseatd of & sign req1(req3) Xor req6(req3 + 256) And &H1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it finally thanks everyone. I had to use "And" keyword inseatd of & sign

```
req1(req3) Xor req6(req3 + 256) And &H1
```